# ADFS 2.0 Best Practices

Tags: single-sign-on, adfs

I'm having a hard time finding some good articles on best practices for ADFS.  We are looking to implement SSO for less than 200 users.  We plan on setting up a federated server farm (2 servers) behind a hardware load balance.  Is a ADFS proxy necessary if we put the federated server farm behind the hardware load balancer?  I need the solution to be redundant however it would seem unnecessary for us to build out 4 servers (2 for ADFS, 2 for proxy).

Comment: Is this for Office 365 integration?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft [outlines counts of servers necessary](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn151324.aspx) as it relates to using ADFS to integrate with Office 365, Azure, and Intune. For Windows Server 2012-based ADFS deployments they call out a minimum of two (2) ADFS servers and two (2) proxies.

Of course, having redundant servers on-site is meaningless if your Internet connection, network infrastructure, and power isn't also redundant. If you're concerned about losing your entire ADFS infrastructure when your servers get carried away by a tornado / flood / rioters then you might consider deploying a redundant ADFS environment, including a Domain Controller, in an off-site hosting facility.

Comment: One other option is to consider migrating that infrastructure to Azure VMs.

Comment: Yep-- in an off-site hosting facility (see my last paragraph). >smile<